# Error in WordPress while establishing connection to database

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

mrtechnic.com and i am unable to open my site its giving me this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string() in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-content/themes/bimber/functions.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-settings.php(425): include() #1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-config.php(30): require_once('/srv/users/serv...') #2 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/srv/users/serv...') #3 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-admin/maint/repair.php(10): require_once('/srv/users/serv...') #4 {main} thrown in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mrtechnic/public/wp-content/themes/bimber/functions.php on line 60
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_escape_string()` is a deprecated function that was removed entirely in PHP7. Your error is because that function is no longer available. You need to update the code.

Keep in mind that in WordPress you shouldn't be interacting with the database using native functions. Use the `wpdb` class instead.

WPDB: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

mysql_escape_string docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php